# QML page content not centered in stackview when page is resized

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have just created a new project selecting the default **Qt Quick Application - Stack** template.

Running the project as is (on a desktop) shows some problem.

1- At first the page contents (which is a simple text) is centered in the window/page as expected due to layaout:

```
anchors.centerIn: parent
```

2- but if I resize the window the "TEXT" position is not changed!!!

3- if i preview just the page via *qmlscene* and resize it, the contents are corectly repositioned in the center as expected.

Q: How can i solve this problem and force the text to be always displayed in the center of the page?

Platform info:

- Qt: 5.12.1
- Qt creator: 4.8.1
- OS: win10

(I did not provide the code, since i used the default code generated by Qt creator for Qt quick stack app)

Thanks in advance

1- As mentioned above, the single pages content is layed out correctly when the page is resized (testing the page standalone via qmlscene)

2- i tried to handle the resize events but i couldn't

```
onWidthChanged: {anchors.centerIn: parent}
```

the erros:

- expected token ','
- Javascript blocks are not supported in qt quick ui form

I tried to do this from the main.qml file but i couldn't

Comment: please provide [mcve] so we can test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HomeForm.ui.qml`, `Page1Form.ui.qml` and `Page2Form.ui.qml` all set:

```
    width: 600
    height: 400
```

This causes those pages to not follow resizes the `StackView`. Unfortunately, those lines are needed when editing those pages in the Designer so you cannot remove them. However, if you add the `anchors.fill: parent` to those pages:

```
    width: 600 // used by the designer
    height: 400 // used by the designer
    anchors.fill: parent // used by the application
```

it will cause those pages to follow the `StackView` geometry. Since the `StackView` already has `anchors.fill: parent` means the `StackView` will resize when the app resizes taking along with the child pages. You should find the centered text will now follow the new center during those resizes.

Comment: thanks a million times, it was really frustrating. i tried many different layouts but i couldn't make it right. As @Stephan mentioned the pages should use the `anchors.fill: parent` layout. I just can't understand why Qt creator's default tempalte app should not follow this layout!!!???